# How do I eliminate the .html from the end of a URL?

Tags: html, url, redirect

I have a website, `www.example.com`. On it, I have a HTML page, accessible by URL `www.example.com/sample.html`.

I want to just type in `www.example.com/sample` and have the browser take me to the page located at `www.example.com/sample.html`. How do I do this? Do I need to set up some sort of redirect?

Comment: This is a server setting. What are you on? IIS/Apache/Other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a directory called `sample` and put the html file renamed to index.html inside of it.

If you don't want to mess around with directories you will need something like mod_rewrite.
Just googled a beginners tutorial for you: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Comment: That's helpful! Thanks.